# Swift/XCode 7: how to temporarily set to use TSL < 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, openssl, xcode7

Waiting for OS X El Capitan (so that I can get TSL 1.2) I enabled my MAMP server to use SSL/TSL. My iOS app uses URLs like the following which correctly work if typed on a browser:

```
static var webServerLoginURL = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/loginM.php"
static var webServerGetUserTasks = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/handleTasks.php"
static var webServerGetUsers = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/handleUsers.php"
static var webServerGetProjects = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/handleProjects.php"
```

Performing:

```
openssl version
```

on a terminal, I get:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

so I edited my plist file adding the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict> <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict> <key>localhost</key> <dict> <!--Include to allow subdomains--> <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/> <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests--> <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                        <true/> <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version--> <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                                <string>TLSv1.0</string> </dict> </dict>    </dict>
```

But, when running the app, I still get:

```
2015-09-21 17:54:17.491 ExcogitoWeb[83336:525096] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-09-21 17:54:17.497 ExcogitoWeb[83336:525096] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-09-21 17:54:17.500 ExcogitoWeb[83336:525096] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-09-21 17:54:17.500 ExcogitoWeb[83336:525096] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

with the consequence that data from the DB are nil and the app crashes. I would like to know why it still refuses to work, even if with a lower SSL/TSL version...can you help?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only set the minimum/maximum protocol version that will be used after protocol negotiation when you use `NSURLSession` for networking where you can set it in the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object in property `TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol`, and the maximum version can be set with property `TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol`.

See [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol)

**Edit**

It seems, there's a way to restrict the accepted TLS protocol versions in lower level APIs as well: 
[iOS 5 and TLS 1.2 Interoperability Issues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2287/_index.html)
(it's a bit old though)

Comment: Hmm...so even if I set the minimum, at the end of the negotiation tls 1.2 will be asked anyway, right?

Comment: You can set min _and_ max version.

Comment: Which version will be negotiated depends on the versions which are supported by both. I would guess, it's the highest matching version.

Comment: So I guess that it will always be 1.2 because iOS 9 simulator has the highest version. I'll try to set the max version as you said. I've read in many sites that SSL/TSL 1.2 will be release with El Capitan...do you know anything about?

Comment: As far as I know, TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are available on iOS 5.0 and later, and OS X 10.8 and later. See here this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.2

Comment: I had read that wiki too. The problem is that I don't know how to upgrade TSL...I tried with brew but it only updated from 0.9.8 to 1.0.2

Comment: @LoryLory These are system libraries - you don't need to update them with brew. OpenSSL is a different implementation.

Comment: :( sorry... I'm an ignorant in terms of security. Is there a way to get 1.2 version or shall I give up and wait for El Capitan?